# zpool states that zones are in SUSPENDED mode

Tags: zsh, solaris, zfs, solaris-zones

Zones are in suspend mode how can I bring them up online?

Operating system:

```
SunOS xxxxxxbase02 5.11 11.2 sun4v sparc sun4v
```

While listing the pool in global zone I can see four hosts are in suspend mode.

```
root@xxxxxxbase02:~# zpool list
NAME                   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CAP  DEDUP     HEALTH  ALTROOT
ZONE-xxxxxxxxxxxq       416G  34.0G   382G   8%  1.00x     ONLINE  -
ZONE-xxxxxxxxxxxw      99.5G  32.3G  67.2G  32%  1.00x     ONLINE  -
ZONE-xxxxxxxxxxxe      99.5G  30.6G  68.9G  30%  1.00x  SUSPENDED  -
ZONE-xxxxxxxxxxxr  99.5G  38.6G  60.9G  38%  1.00x  SUSPENDED  -
ZONE-xxxxxxxxxxxt  99.5G  44.6G  54.9G  44%  1.00x  SUSPENDED  -
ZONE-xxxxxxxxxxxy     99.5G  4.35G  95.1G   4%  1.00x  SUSPENDED  -
datapool               278G   265G  13.0G  95%  1.00x     ONLINE  -
rpool                  278G   267G  11.1G  96%  1.00x     ONLINE  -
vmpool                99.5G  26.3G  73.2G  26%  1.00x     ONLINE  -
zonepool               556G   253G   303G  45%  1.00x     ONLINE  -
zones                  556G   279G   277G  50%  1.00x     ONLINE  -
```

I have tried bringing up the zone using

```
# zoneadm -z xxxxxxxxx boot
```

This throws the below errors

```
root@xxxxxxbase02:~# zoneadm -z xxxxxxxxxxx boot
zoneadm: zone 'xxxxxxxxxxx': unable to open dataset rpool/ROOT/solaris-11.2.2.2.8/xxxxxxxxxxx: filesystem does not exist
could not verify zonepath /xxxxxxxxxxx because of the above errors.
zoneadm: xxxxxxxxxxx: Could not set state to unavailable: Problem creating temporary file
zoneadm: zone 'xxxxxxxxxxx': failed to open dladm handle: operation failed
Abort
```

I have tried to access the console using zlogin -C options still I can't just it freeze the screen.

```
# zlogin -C xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have checked the services for the suspended zone I can see every services are in sleep mode.

```
# prstat -z xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: "filesystem does not exist" have you checked if that dataset actually exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **do not mix zones and zpools concepts**
   Your zones are on top of zpools and these zpools are in suspended.

first fix the zpool:
Check status

```
zpool status <zpool-name>
```

then depending on the output take the proper action to fix it. Ensure that your devices disks that are part of the zpools are there.

Check Oracle Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E37384/gbbba.html)

Comment: yes its unavailable.. thanks for pointing